# How to update old project dependencies versions into latest android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am learning one android project from youtube but that video is published 2 years ago. Now in order to use that code what changes i have to do in dependencies of libraries like room , Okhttp etcc and how can i update that project to latest verison easily?

Comment: Android Studio will highlight out of date version numbers in your gradle file. You can hover over these and click the option to update to the latest version.

Comment: you can take a look at their official websites. For eg, you can refer this for [Okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the dependencies as listed, they *should* still work - repositories keep the older versions, so projects built with a particular set of dependencies can pull those versions and build the same output no matter how old it is. Nothing *has to* update to a new version of a library - and many actively maintained projects will choose to stay on an older version of a dependency for lots of reasons!

That said, if you're creating a new project right now, some of the current Android framework libraries, plugins etc. might require certain versions of other dependencies - they might force you to meet some minimum version requirements, just because they're incompatible with older versions. You could either downgrade all the stuff that complains about needing a newer version of X, or you could upgrade your old dependencies, like you're asking about.

An easy way to do it is to open the *Project Structure* window in the *File* menu, and go to the *Dependencies* section. It'll show you all the dependencies in your project, identify which ones are out of date, and you can select an available version you want, or just update to the most recent version.

---

But if there *is* a compatibility issue, it might take some time to work out which versions are necessary, or even which versions are being pulled in by other libraries (e.g. a particular version of a library might internally have a dependency on a certain version of a library you're already using, and the most recent one is what your project ends up using). You can get some info about this from the output in the *Build* window, or maybe running the `dependencies` Gradle task if you want to explore that.

It wouldn't hurt to look at the project pages for your libraries and see what they say about installation and dependencies. Also, their method for adding them to a project might have changes, e.g. something that used the (now closed) *JCenter* repository might be using *Jitpack* now. Something to look at if you're having problems.

Also there's the issue that new versions of the libraries might have different APIs, or their behaviour might have changed. Even if fully updating everything goes smoothly, there might be stuff you need to fix in the code itself. Just a few things to keep in mind!

Comment: Yes it works I can run that project without updating libraries to latest versions . Thank you very much sir!